# Route path is treated as param

Tags: reactjs

I am using `react-router-dom` to configure the routes as follows:

```
const router = createBrowserRouter({
    {
        path: "/test/:name/:code",
        element: <MyElement />,
    }
    ...
}

...
root.render(
    <RouterProvider router={router} />
);
```

In `MyElement`, I used `useParams` from `react-router-dom` to retrieve the query params and call another api with the values of `name` and `code`.

```
const { name, code } = useParams();
myService.getPage(name, code).then(,,,
```

In `myService`, I call the api as follows:

```
getPage(name: string, code: string): Promise<any> {
    return axios.get(`http://localhost:8080/api/page?name=${name}&code=${code}`, {});
}
```

In the backend, the name is urlencoded.  So if the name is `you & me`, it is saved
in the database as `you+%26+me`. Given an example code of `123`, a call to `http://localhost:3000/test/you+%26+me/123` will render the `MyElement` component.  But the request made by `myService` will be `http://localhost:8080/api/page?name=you+&+me&code=123`. Now it appears as if there are 3 query params: "name", "me", and "code".  The backend will only receive `you` for name and `123` for code.

If I encode first the url as follows:

```
myService.getPage(encodeURIComponent(name), code).then(,,,
```

The request made by `myService` will be `http://localhost:8080/api/page?name=you%2B%26%2Bme&code=123`.  The backend (which is written in Java and Spring) will see the name as `you+&+me`.  The backend will not recognize the name because the one saved in the database is `you+%26+me` and not `you+&+me`.

Comment: You shouldn't store things urlencoded in the database, encoding is only for transfer not storage

Comment: Axios has a `params` option for correctly encoding query parameters. I recommend you use it

Comment: using `params` works but I also need to change the encoding in the backend to use `UriUtils.encode()` to encode the sample text to `you%20%26%20me` instead of `you+%26+me`